# Unable to ssh to localhost on macOS: "Connection closed by ::1 port 22" as newly created user

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm running macOS 10.14.6 on an iMac named `angharad`. It's generally working fine.

I have created a new user account named `alice` to use for testing an SSH client. I can log in as `alice` using the Mac desktop interface, and I can `su - alice` no problem. But I cannot ssh in to localhost as this user. When I do so, I just get a "Connection closed" message.

```
[~] $ ssh alice@localhost
Password:
Connection closed by ::1 port 22
[~] $
```

I am definitely entering the password correctly.

I can `ssh localhost` or `ssh janke@localhost` using my main `janke` account just fine.

When I look at `/var/log/system.log`, I see one of these appear each time I try to make a connection:

```
Apr 19 22:48:28 angharad login[29662]: USER_PROCESS: 29662 ttys002
Apr 19 22:48:35 angharad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.E37AD3EB-1E30-4F30-B96A-FBE9B2240D7F[29710]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

(and then a bunch of spam from Electron apps and the Microsoft Remote Desktop client.)

Then I looked in Console and found this:

```
23:10:34.899109   sshd      error: PAM: user account has expired for alice from ::1
23:1034:908664    sshd      fatal: monitor_read: unpermitted request 104
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Check the system log for ssh-related messages - on my MacOS 10.13 box that would be /var/log/system.log. I don't have a 10.14 box handy but "log show --style syslog | grep ssh" might work.

Comment: I see something! Updated my question with the log contents.

Comment: There should be more sshd messages about exactly why it failed. Note that /var/log/system.log no longer contains all the logs, use the "log" command in my comment above (and be patient, it will be slow).

Comment: ugh, Apple really made life difficult for people trying to look for logs in recent MacOS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382825/where-to-find-sshd-logs-on-macos-sierra for more details on finding sshd logs.

Comment: Thanks Velo! I looked in Console and found this (details added to question): `sshd      error: PAM: user account has expired for alice from ::1`. "User account has expired"? I dunno what to do with that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The log message says that the "alice" user account is expired. But that makes no sense, since the user can log in successfully in other contexts. I did a little research and found this:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/smoke/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Enabling-remote-SSH-login-on-Mac-OS-X.html

TL;DR: go into System Preferences, Sharing, then click on "Remote Login" and adjust the access list to include the new user. Presumably for safety's sake, ssh logins need to be set up in this access list. It works for you because administrative accounts are allowed by default.

Comment: Boom! Fixed. Thank you Velo. Wish the error message were more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The key part for me was to explicitly add the users in the access list. I am now able to ssh between users on the same machine

Comment: It might close your connection even if you select "all users".  If this happens you can fix it by switching to "only these users" and then back to "all users", then you've got maybe 5m to connect, after which it will start refusing you again.  If you're thinking "no way, that's bonkers", you're absolutely right, it is.